# shop_item_id must be valid

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm working with this avatar community engine built on CodeIgniter, everything is working except the shop system.

Every time I try to buy an item I get this:

> **An Error Was Encountered**
>
> shop_item_id must be valid

I've narrowed the problem to this piece of code:

```
public function purchase_item()
{
    $shop_item_id = $this->input->post('item_id');

    if(!is_numeric($shop_item_id)) show_error('shop_item_id must be valid');

    $shop_item_query = $this->db->join('avatar_items', 'avatar_items.item_id = shop_items.item_id')->get_where('shop_items', array('shop_item_id' => $shop_item_id));

    if($shop_item_query->num_rows() > 0):
        $shop_item_data = $shop_item_query->row_array();
    else:
        show_error('shop_item could not be found.');
    endif;

    $shop_id = $shop_item_data['shop_id'];

    if ( ! $shop_data = $this->cache->get('shop_data_'.$shop_id)):
        $shop_data = $this->db->get_where('shops', array('shop_id' => $shop_id))->row_array();
        $this->cache->save('shop_data_'.$shop_id, $shop_data, 2400);
    endif;
```

What is the solution?

p.s: I'm using the script of crysandrea (https://github.com/tylerdiaz/Crysandrea). I need this for my assignment.

Here's the code:

```
        <form action="/shops/purchase_item/" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="<?php echo $item_data['shop_item_id'] ?>" />
        <button type="submit" class="main_button">Purchase item</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: your `item_id` is string or integer value your passing?

Comment: please do `echo $shop_item_id = $this->input->post('item_id');` this and check what you getting, string or integer?

Comment: tried echoing it, still showed an error. @rits

Comment: just put exit; below that line so the execution stops and we can see echoed value.

Comment: returns a blank page.

Comment: after `$shop_item_id = $this->input->post('item_id');` please write `die(var_dump($shop_item_id))` and share the result

Comment: okay then your `item_id` is not reaching to your method.

Comment: check in your form. the problem is in your form might be

Comment: @AkshitArora i got bool(false)

Comment: @KennedyBrown, Rits is right then, you are getting false in your item id. Do check in your form...

Comment: wait, let me put the form code

Comment: edoted my post, please check it out

Comment: `<input type="hidden"` change type to `text` and check the value is there or not?

Comment: there is, it's the item's id

Comment: Again, in your view file, can you execute and show the result of `$item_data['shop_item_id']`??

Comment: can you please open inspector in your form page and scroll to your form code and tell us what is the value of this 
        <input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="<?php echo $item_data['shop_item_id'] ?>" />

Comment: And the value should be just numbers if there is dot or any character it will return false

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You forget semicolon. now try following code

```
  <form action="/shops/purchase_item/" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="<?php echo $item_data['shop_item_id']; ?>" />
        <button type="submit" class="main_button">Purchase item</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write this code in function

```
 if(!is_numeric((int)$shop_item_id)) show_error('shop_item_id must be valid');
```